# Different text positioning for single line and multi-line text

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to set different text positioning for single line and multi-line text with using just CSS?

For example: I want my single short line of text to be center aligned, but when text exceeds single line length and becomes multi-line text, it should be left aligned.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of different `text-align` and `display` values to achieve that.

```css
.outer {
  text-align: center; /*center the inner inline block mainly*/
  display: block; /*not needed here but if using nested <span>s*/
}
.inner {
  text-align: left; /*reset the text to be left aligned*/
  display: inline-block; /*the width of the box based on content length*/
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" is an English-language pangram—a phrase that contains all of the letters of the alphabet. It is commonly used for touch-typing practice.</div>
</div>
```

You can also use [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), it makes it easy for vertically centering the text too.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /*center horizontally*/
  align-items: center; /*center vertically*/
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" is an English-language pangram—a phrase that contains all of the letters of the alphabet. It is commonly used for touch-typing practice.
</div>
```

One more way would be using CSS table for centering horizontally, similarly to the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38341875/483779) suggestion, but also using CSS table cell for centering vertically.

```css
.outer {
  display: table;
  margin: auto; /*center horizontally*/
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle; /*center vertically*/
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" is an English-language pangram—a phrase that contains all of the letters of the alphabet. It is commonly used for touch-typing practice.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Clever! My solution was long and jQuery-ish, but this is so much better...

Comment: @pangloss: Thanks. Can you please tell me is it also possible to make it vertically centered?

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS tables:

```css
div {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto; /* Center container horizonatlly */
  text-align: left; /* Align text to the left */
}
```

```html
<div>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</div>
<hr />
<div>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</div>
```

CSS tables work because they are sized using the shrink-to-fit algorithm, but are still block-level in-flow elements. CSS3 exposes this size via the `fit-content` keyword, so you no longer have to rely on weird tabular layouts, but it's not widely supported yet.

```css
div {
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto; /* Center container horizonatlly */
  text-align: left; /* Align text to the left */
}
```

```html
<div>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</div>
<hr />
<div>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me the way to make it vertically centered as well?

Comment: @RohanPatel [How to vertically center text with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8865458/1529630)

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a way to do this in CSS, though it could be done in JavaScript. I would start with using string.length to determine the character count (although different fonts render differently and different characters may have different widths). From there you could use jQuery or selectElement(s)By* to add and remove alignments via classes or css.